# Trying to find a temperature profile with a nonlinear 2nd order ODE. NDSolve very sensitive to seemingly arbitrary constant

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

I am trying to solve this differential equation for a heat transfer problem:
\begin{equation}
kt\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} = \epsilon \sigma T^4, \ \ \ T(0) = T_0, \ \ \ \frac{\partial T}{\partial x} \Big|_{x=L} = 0
\end{equation}

where $k$, $t$, $\epsilon$, $\sigma$, $T_0$ and $L$ are constants.

Mathematica's `NDSolve` won't touch this. However, substituting with the dimensionless $\Theta = \frac{T}{T_0}$ and $\rho = \frac{x}{L}$, the problem becomes

\begin{equation}
A\frac{\partial^2 \Theta}{\partial \rho^2} = \Theta^4, \ \ \ \Theta(0) = 1, \ \ \ \frac{\partial \Theta}{\partial \rho} \Big|_{\rho=1} = 0
\end{equation}

Where $A = \frac{kt}{L^2 T_0^3 \epsilon \sigma}$ is a constant  (feel free to double check this, but I am pretty confident with the math).

Pluging this into Mathematica like so

```
T0 = 238;
L = 1.5;
A = 0.001356;
tau = NDSolve[{A*Th''[r] == Th[r]^4, Th'[1] == 0, Th[0] == 1}, Th, {r, 0, 1}];
T[x_] = Evaluate[T0*Th[x/L]/.tau];
Plot[T[x] - 273, {x, 0, L}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x [m]", "T [°C]"}]
```

gives me

```
NDSolve::ndsz: At r == 0.0530353097865862`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>
```

However, with the wrong equation (setting $A=1$):

```
tau = NDSolve[{Th''[r] == Th[r]^4, Th'[1] == 0, Th[0] == 1}, Th, {r, 0, 1}]
```

I get a nice, wrong temperature profile.

What gives? I feel like this is a math issue rather than a coding one, but I may be wrong.

I there a mathematical route to using the $\frac{\partial^2 \Theta}{\partial \rho^2} = \Theta^4$ solution and scale it with $A$ somehow, or should I be able to solve the real equation with Mathematica?

Thank you.

**Edit:** This is getting weirder. I ran `A=1; tau = NDSolve[{A*Th''[r] == Th[r]^4, Th'[1] == 0, Th[0] == 1}, Th, {r, 0, 1}]; T[x_] = Evaluate[Th[x]/.tau]; Plot[T[x], {x, 0, 1}]` for different values of A, and NDSolve only crashes for values smaller than `A = 0.4821`. I have no idea where to go from there. The correct value for A is `A = 0.001356`.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Do you have any a priori idea what the solution should look like?  Since it's a boundary value problem, you might look into Mathematica's Shooting method: maybe you could give better initial guesses for Th'[0].

Comment: If you run 

    `tau = NDSolve[{Th''[r] == Th[r]^4, Th'[1] == 0, Th[0] == 1}, Th, {r, 0, 1}];
    T[x_] = Evaluate[Th[x]/.tau];
    Plot[T[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]`

you will see what the solution looks like. $T'(0) < 0$ in this solution, which is correct. However, the real values do not match the physical units in this reduced solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `Method->"Shooting"` in `NDSolve` it helps to give good initial guesses.  For example,

```
A = 0.001356;
tau = NDSolve[{A*Th''[r] == Th[r]^4, Th'[1] == 0, Th[0] == 1}, Th, {r, 0, 1}, 
Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {Th[0] == 1, Th'[0] == -17.1747}}];
```

seems to work fine.

Your problem seems very sensitive to that initial slope.  How'd I get that crazy guess?  I started with a solvable `A` value and then decreased it, using linear extrapolation to update the initial guess.  Since `A` seems to vary over orders of magnitude, I stepped through it in fractional powers of 10.

```
Clear[A];
DTh0 = -0.5; (* initial guess *)
DTh = -0.5; (* "" *)
dAp = -0.01; (* A power step size *)
res = {};
Do[
  A = 10.^Ap;
  tau = NDSolve[{A*Th''[r] == Th[r]^4, Th'[1] == 0, Th[0] == 1}, Th, {r, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {Th[0] == 1, Th'[0] == DTh0}}][[1]];

  DThold = DTh;
  DTh = Th'[0] /. tau;
  DTh0 = 2 DTh - DThold; (* linear extrapolation for next guess *)

  AppendTo[res, {A, DTh}];
,{Ap, 0, -3, dAp}]
```

Then to get the guess for your `A` value,

```
Interpolation[res][0.001356]
(* -17.1747 *)
```

It's sort of a hack of a solution. Hopefully someone can offer a more sophisticated approach!

Comment: This is amazing, thank you. Now my answer is off, because this is a heat in = heat out problem such that $-kT'(0) = \int_0^L \epsilon \sigma T^4$, which is not true with the solution I just got, but now I can actually focus on the physics to sort this out!

Comment: Cannot edit my previous comment, but the solution is in fact correct, because the balance is actually $-ktT'(0) = \int_0^L \epsilon \sigma T^4$. All good.

Answer (score 4):

Because the ODE is autonomous (i.e., `r` does not appear explicitly in it), it is "almost" possible to solve it symbolically, starting with `DSolve` with boundary conditions omitted.  (`DSolve` returns unevaluated, if boundary conditions are included.)

```
DSolve[A*Th''[r] == Th[r]^4, Th, r]
(* Solve[(Hypergeometric2F1[1/5, 1/2, 6/5, -((2 Th[r]^5)/(5 A C[1]))]^2 Th[
r]^2 
   (5 C[1] + (2 Th[r]^5)/A))/(C[1]^2 (5 + (2 Th[r]^5)/(A C[1]))) == (r + C[2])^2, Th[r]] *)
```

To determine the two constants, extract and simply the resulting equation.

```
Simplify[First@%]
(* (Hypergeometric2F1[1/5, 1/2, 6/5, -((2 Th[r]^5)/(5 A C[1]))]^2 Th[r]^2)/C[1] == 
   (r + C[2])^2 *)
```

Next, take the square root of both sides of the equation, for which a positive or negative sign must be assumed for `r + C[2]`.  Choose the latter.

```
Reverse[Simplify[Sqrt[#], r + C[2] < 0 && 
    Hypergeometric2F1[1/5, 1/2, 6/5, -((2 Th[r]^5)/(5 A C[1]))] Th[r] > 0] & /@ %]
(* -r - C[2] == Sqrt[1/C[1]]
   Hypergeometric2F1[1/5, 1/2, 6/5, -((2 Th[r]^5)/(5 A C[1]))] Th[r] *)
```

Applying the `Th[0] == 1` boundary condition readily determines `C[2]`.

```
Rule @@ (% /. r -> 0 /. Th[0] -> 1);
eq1 = (%% /. %) /. C[1] -> -2 c/(5 A)
(* -r + Sqrt[5/2] Sqrt[-(A/c)] Hypergeometric2F1[1/5, 1/2, 6/5, 1/c] == 
   Sqrt[5/2] Sqrt[-(A/c)]Hypergeometric2F1[1/5, 1/2, 6/5, Th[r]^5/c] Th[r] *)
```

where the substitution `C[1] -> -2 c/(5 A)` has been introduced for simplicity.  Next, apply the `Th'[1] == 0` boundary condition.

```
FullSimplify[D[eq1, r]] /. r -> 1
(* 2 + (Sqrt[10] Sqrt[-(A/c)] Th'[1])/Sqrt[1 - Th[1]^5/c] == 0 *)
```

which cannot be satisfied unless `c == Th[1]^5`.

```
eq2 = eq1 /. c -> Th[1]^5
(* -r + Sqrt[5/2]Hypergeometric2F1[1/5, 1/2, 6/5, 1/Th[1]^5] Sqrt[-(A/Th[1]^5)] == 
   Sqrt[5/2] Hypergeometric2F1[1/5, 1/2, 6/5, Th[r]^5/Th[1]^5] Sqrt[-(A/Th[1]^5)] Th[r] *)
```

`eq2` plus the boundary condition `eq2/.r -> 0` uniquely determine `Th[r]`.  However, `Th[1]` must be computed numerically, here for `A == 1356 10^-6`.

```
FindRoot[eq2 /. r -> 1 /. A -> 1356 10^-6, {Th[1], 1/10}, MaxIterations -> 1000] // Chop
eq3 = eq2 /. % /. A -> 1356 10^-6
(* {Th[1] -> 0.137621} *)
(* (1. + 1.42981 I) - r == 
   (0. + 8.28684 I) Hypergeometric2F1[1/5, 1/2, 6/5, 20257.2 Th[r]^5] Th[r] *)
```

which can be plotted parametrically.  (Note that, if `r + C[2] > 0` had been assumed when square roots were taken above, `eq2` now would have no real zeroes for `Th[1]`).

```
temin = Th[1] /. %%;
arg = {Subtract @@ eq3 /. Th[r] -> tem /. r -> 0, tem};
ParametricPlot[arg // Chop, {tem, temin, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {.1, 1}}, AxesLabel -> {r, Th}, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 14], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

`Th[1]` as a function of `A` can be plotted in a similar way.

```
Equal @@ (Solve[eq2 /. r -> 1, A][[1, 1]])
(* A == -((2 Gamma[7/10]^2 Th[1]^5)/(5 (Gamma[7/10] 
   Hypergeometric2F1[1/5, 1/2, 6/5, 1/Th[1]^5] - Sqrt[π] Gamma[6/5] Th[1])^2)) *)

arg = {Last[%] /. Th[1] -> tem, tem};
ParametricPlot[arg // Chop, {tem, 10^-3, 1/2}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
    AxesLabel -> {A, "Th[1]"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 14], 
    ImageSize -> Large, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{1356 10^-6, temin}]}]
```

[image]

Values of `{Th[1], A}` for the first plot are superimposed as a red dot.  That it lies on the steep part of the curve may explain the difficulty encountered by the OP in solving the ODE numerically.