# Stiff coupled system of ODE's

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

I am having trouble with a possible stiff nonlinear system of ODE's.

```
Eqn1 = 
  D[Psi[r], {r, 4}] - XX1*D[D[Psi[r], {r, 2}]^3, {r, 2}] + 
  D[P[r], {r, 1}] - D[Psi[r], {r, 2}] == 0;

Eqn2 = D[P[r], {r, 2}] + D[Psi[r], {r, 2}]*(1 - XX1*D[Psi[r], {r, 2}]^2) == 0;

Eqns = 
 {Eqn1, Eqn2, 
  Psi[1.5] == 0.75, 
  Psi[-1.] == -0.75, 
  Psi'[1.5] == -1, 
  Psi'[-1.] == -1, 
  P[1.5] == 0, 
  P[-1.] == 1}

XX1 = 1;

sol = NDSolve[Eqns, {Psi, P}, {r, -1, 1.5}]
```

`XX1` is the one parameter which is causing the problems. Because this `XX1` is the coefficient of the nonlinear term in the ODE's. If I choose this `XX1` to be something other than zero, the system becomes nonlinear and then `NDSolve` does not converge.

Comment: Have a look ["StiffnessSwitching" Method for NDSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessSwitching.html) and [Stiffness Detection](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessTest.html)

Comment: @Louis I had a look to your suggestions but no luck with it. I tried the different approaches discussed in the documentations.

Comment: I have been able to solve these equations for `xx1` as large as `8.65 10^-3`.  However, as `xx1` increases, `psi'''[-1]` becomes quite large in absolute value, and probably become singular for sufficiently large `xx1`.

Comment: Because `p[r]`, `psi[r]`, and `psi'[r]` do not appear in the ODEs themselves and only in the boundary conditions, the ODEs can be rewritten in terms of `q[r]` in place of `p'[r]` and `qsi[r]` in place of `psi''[r]`, in which case the boundary conditions are replaced by integrals over the solutions for `q[r]` and `qsi[r]`.  This approach could very well be more accurate.

Comment: Also, it might be interesting to linearize the ODEs in `xx1` about the solution for `xx1 = 0` and then solve the linearized equations.  Of course, this approach would break down well before `xx1 = 1`.

Comment: With some help, I manage to solve it using maple for `XX1=c*0.045` where `c` is the continuation.

Comment: @MMM  What is the value of `c`, so that the actual value of `XX!` can be determined?

Comment: @bbgodfrey I do not know. This `c` is a continuation parameter, which is used in the `dsolve` command as `continuation=c`.

Comment: @MMM  Is it possible that you meant `XX1=c*0.0045` in your earlier comment?  Thanks.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yes!

Comment: Is there some method to avoid stiff problem? A given problem may have a stable solution, if we change variables or methods, is it possible to get non-stiff equations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative approach, more accurate and efficient, is as follows.  Consider the two ODEs in the question, slightly restructured.

```
eqn1 = D[D[psi[r], {r, 2}] (1 - xx1*D[psi[r], {r, 2}]^2), {r, 2}] + 
    D[p[r], {r, 1}] - D[psi[r], {r, 2}] == 0
eqn2 = D[p[r], {r, 2}] + D[psi[r], {r, 2}] (1 - xx1*D[psi[r], {r, 2}]^2) == 0
```

`psi[r]`, `psi'[r]`, and `p[r]` do not enter explicitly into these equations.  Therefore, define `qsi[r]` as `Sqrt[xx1] psi''[r]` and `q[r]` as `p'[r]`, so that the equations become

```
qn1 = D[qsi[r] (1 - qsi[r]^2), {r, 2}] + q[r] - qsi[r] == 0
qn2 = D[q[r], {r, 1}] + qsi[r]*(1 - qsi[r]^2) == 0
```

A modest amount of algebra shows that the boundary conditions become

```
NIntegrate[q[r], {r, -1, 3/2}] + Sqrt[xx1] == 0
NIntegrate[qsi[r], {r, -1, 3/2}] == 0
NIntegrate[r qsi[r], {r, -1, 3/2}] + 4 Sqrt[xx1] == 0
```

Next, define `t[r]` as `qsi[r] - qsi[r]^3` to eliminate the singularity in `qn1` at `qsi[r] = 1`.

```
qsi /. FullSimplify[Solve[t == qsi - qsi^3, qsi, Reals], 
    -(2/(3 Sqrt[3])) < t < 2/(3 Sqrt[3])]
(* {Root[t - #1 + #1^3 &, 1], Root[t - #1 + #1^3 &, 2], Root[t - #1 + #1^3 &, 3]} *)
Plot[%, {t, -(2/(3 Sqrt[3])), 2/(3 Sqrt[3])}, AxesLabel -> {t, qsi}, 
    PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

With the second branch of this final transformation, the equations and boundary conditions become

```
qn1 = D[t[r], {r, 2}] + q[r] - Root[t[r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 2] == 0
qn2 = D[q[r], {r, 1}] + t[r] == 0
NIntegrate[q[r], {r, -1, 3/2}] + Sqrt[xx1] == 0
NIntegrate[Root[t[r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 2], {r, -1, 3/2}] == 0
NIntegrate[r Root[t[r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 2], {r, -1, 3/2}] +4 Sqrt[xx1] == 0
```

The second and third integrals are real only for `-(2/(3 Sqrt[3])) < t < 2/(3 Sqrt[3])`.  The absence of answers to [110534](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110534/1063) suggests that this requirement cannot be imposed using `NDSolve` with `Method -> "Shooting"`.  Instead, use `FindRoot` directly.

```
xx1 = 8.7677 10^-3;
qn1 = D[t[r], {r, 2}] + q[r] - Root[t[r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 2] == 0;
qn2 = D[q[r], {r, 1}] + t[r] == 0;
qns = {qn1, qn2, t[-1] == a, t'[-1] == b, q[-1] == c};
st = ParametricNDSolve[qns, {t, q}, {r, -1, 3/2}, {a, b, c}, MaxStepFraction -> 1/1000];
int1[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
    NIntegrate[q[a, b, c][r] /. st, {r, -1, 3/2}] + Sqrt[xx1];
int2[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
    NIntegrate[Root[t[a, b, c][r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 2] /. st, {r, -1, 3/2}];
int3[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
    NIntegrate[r Root[t[a, b, c][r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 2] /. st, {r, -1, 3/2}] + 4 Sqrt[xx1];
qval = Quiet@FindRoot[{int1[a, b, c], int2[a, b, c], int3[a, b, c]}, 
    {a, 0.3848882573269839`, .3, 2/(3 Sqrt[3]) }, {b, -0.4895029166208631`}, 
    {c, 0.0935952879725864`}, MaxIterations -> 500]
Unevaluated[{int1[a, b, c], int2[a, b, c], int3[a, b, c]}] /. %
Plot[Evaluate[{Root[t[a, b, c][r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 2], 
    t[a, b, c]'[r]/(1 - 3 Root[t[a, b, c][r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 2]^2), 
    q[a, b, c][r]} /. st /. %%], {r, -1, 3/2}]
Plot[Evaluate[{t[a, b, c][r], t[a, b, c]'[r], q[a, b, c][r]} /. st /. %%%], {r, -1, 3/2}, 
    AxesLabel -> {r, "qsi, qsi', q"}]
(* {a -> 0.384898, b -> -0.489519, c -> 0.0935965} *)
(* {-9.71445*10^-17, -6.99907*10^-16, -8.88178*10^-16} *)
```

[image]

This particular `xx1` has been chosen to yield `t[-1] = a = 0.384898`, which is very close to `2/(3 Sqrt[3])`, indicating that `xx1 = 8.7677 10^-3` is a very good approximation to the upper bound on `xx1`, above which the boundary conditions cannot be satisfied.

`psi[r]` and `p[r]` can be obtained by straightforward integration of `qsi[r]` and `q[r]`.

```
sp = NDSolve[{D[psi[r], {r, 2}] == Root[t[a, b, c][r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 2]/Sqrt[xx1] /. st 
    /. qval, D[p[r], r] == q[a, b, c][r]/Sqrt[xx1] /. st /. qval, 
    psi[-1] == -3/4, psi'[-1] == -1, p[-1] == 1}, {psi, p}, {r, -1, 3/2}];
Plot[Evaluate[{psi[r], p[r]} /. sp], {r, -1, 3/2}, AxesLabel -> {r, "psi, p"}]
```

[image]

**Addendum: Direct calculation of xx1 upper bound**

Determining the upper bound on `xx1` turns out to be surprisingly easy, given a good initial guess.  Set `t[-1] == 2/(3 Sqrt[3])`, the maximum value it can assume, and vary `xx1` with `FindRoot`

```
Clear[xx1];
qn1 = D[t[r], {r, 2}] + q[r] - Root[t[r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 2] == 0;
qn2 = D[q[r], {r, 1}] + t[r] == 0;
qns = {qn1, qn2, t[-1] == 2/(3 Sqrt[3]), t'[-1] == b, q[-1] == c};
st = ParametricNDSolve[qns, {t, q}, {r, -1, 3/2}, {b, c}, MaxStepFraction -> 1/1000];
int1[xx1_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
    NIntegrate[q[b, c][r] /. st, {r, -1, 3/2}] + Sqrt[xx1];
int2[xx1_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
    NIntegrate[Root[t[b, c][r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 2] /. st, {r, -1, 3/2}];
int3[xx1_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
    NIntegrate[r Root[t[b, c][r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 2] /. st, {r, -1, 3/2}] + 4 Sqrt[xx1];
qvql = Quiet@FindRoot[{int1[xx1, b, c], int2[xx1, b, c], int3[xx1, b, c]}, 
    {xx1, 8.7677 10^-3}, {b, -0.4895029166208631`}, {c, 0.0935952879725864`},
    MaxIterations -> 500]
Unevaluated[{int1[xx1, b, c], int2[xx1, b, c], int3[xx1, b, c]}] /. %
Plot[Evaluate[{Root[t[b, c][r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 2], 
   t[b, c]'[r]/(1 - 3 Root[t[b, c][r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 2]^2), 
   q[b, c][r]} /. st /. %%], {r, -1, 3/2}, AxesLabel -> {r, "qsi, qsi', q"}]
(* {xx1 -> 0.00876784, b -> -0.489523, c -> 0.0935967} *)
(* {2.26208*10^-15, 1.27339*10^-13, 1.94289*10^-14} *)
```

Thus, the upper bound is `xx1 = 0.00876784`.  The corresponding `Plot` is indistinguishable from the second to the last one above.

**Second Addendum: Solutions above the "upper bound"**

As suggested by [MMM](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/8538/mmm), it is possible - although more difficult - to obtain solutions for `xx1` greater than the purported upper bound given in the last section.  Doing so requires using branch `3` and often branch `1`, as well as branch `2` of the `t` transform plotted in the first figure.  The following code accomplishes this.

```
Clear[st]; r1 = -1; r2 = 3/2; xx1 = 2.5 10^-2;
qns = {D[q[r], {r, 1}] + t[r] == 0, t[-1] == a, t'[-1] == b, 
    q[-1] == c, n[-1] == If[xx1 > 0.008767841540390384`, 3, 2], 
  WhenEvent[t[r] > 2/(3 Sqrt[3]) - 10^-4, {n[r] -> 2, t'[r] -> -t'[r], r1 = r, r2 = 3/2}], 
    WhenEvent[t[r] < -2/(3 Sqrt[3]) + 10^-4, {n[r] -> 1, t'[r] -> -t'[r], r2 = r}]};
st = ParametricNDSolve[{qns, D[t[r], {r, 2}] + q[r] == Root[t[r] - #1 + #1^3 &, n[r]]}, 
    {t, q, n}, {r, -1, 3/2}, {a, b, c}, MaxStepFraction -> 1/1000, 
    DiscreteVariables -> {n[r] \[Element] {1, 2, 3}}];
int1[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
    Chop@NIntegrate[q[a, b, c][r] /. st, {r, -1, 3/2}] + Sqrt[xx1];
int2[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
    NIntegrate[Root[t[a, b, c][r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 3] /. st, {r, -1, r1}] + 
    NIntegrate[Root[t[a, b, c][r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 2] /. st, {r, r1, r2}] + 
    NIntegrate[Root[t[a, b, c][r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 1] /. st, {r, r2, 3/2}];
int3[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
    NIntegrate[r Root[t[a, b, c][r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 2] /. st, {r, -1, r1}] + 
    NIntegrate[r Root[t[a, b, c][r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 2] /. st, {r, r1, r2}] + 
    NIntegrate[r Root[t[a, b, c][r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 1] /. st, {r, r2, 3/2}] + 4 Sqrt[xx1];
qval = Quiet@FindRoot[{int1[a, b, c], int2[a, b, c], int3[a, b, c]}, 
    {a, 0.26367683907672707`, -2/(3 Sqrt[3]), 2/(3 Sqrt[3])}, 
    {b, 0.40781910948554423`}, {c, 0.0918387339602277`}]
Unevaluated[{int1[a, b, c], int2[a, b, c], int3[a, b, c]}] /. %
Plot[Evaluate[{Piecewise[{{Root[t[a, b, c][r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 2], 
    r1 < r < r2}, {Root[t[a, b, c][r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 3], 
    r <= r1}, {Root[t[a, b, c][r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 1], r2 <= r}}], 
    t[a, b, c]'[r]/(1 - 3 Piecewise[{{Root[t[a, b, c][r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 2], 
    r1 < r < r2}, {Root[t[a, b, c][r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 3], 
    r <= r1}, {Root[t[a, b, c][r] - #1 + #1^3 &, 1], r2 <= r}}]^2), 
    q[a, b, c][r]} /. st /. %%], {r, -1, 3/2}, AxesLabel -> {r, "qsi, qsi', q"}]
Plot[Evaluate[{t[a, b, c][r], t[a, b, c]'[r], q[a, b, c][r]} /. 
st /. %%%], {r, -1, 3/2}, AxesLabel -> {r, "t, t', q"}, Exclusions -> {r1, r2}]
(* {a -> 0.219976, b -> 0.368499, c -> 0.0839676} *)
(* {-1.38255*10^-10, 4.27128*10^-10, 4.16582*10^-10} *)
```

[image]
[image]

`t` and `t'`are included for completeness in the second plot.

The guess `a`, equal to `t[-1]`, needed to obtain a solution becomes smaller as `xx1` becomes larger, and some experimentation is necessary to obtain a sufficiently good value.  Even then, computing the curves for a given `xx1` takes several minutes on my computer.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your efforts. It seems that only for a very small value of `XX1` you made it possible to have a solution to the given system. For analysis, I need to vary `XX1` at least between `0` and `1`. Will it be wise to use `FDM`? If yes then how can we do it in Mathematica?

Comment: @MMM  Not all systems of nonlinear ODEs have solutions.  Do you have evidence that this system does for large `xxi`?  If it does, solving it probably will involve integrating across a singularity.  Finite Difference Methods typically fail at singularities, although this one appears to have the character Sqrt[r-r0], which offers some hope.

Comment: I do not have any evidence. I just hope that it will be nice to be able to solve this system for higher values of `XX1` .

Comment: @MMM  A large `xx1` solution may be possible, but obtaining it will be difficult.  I could take another look, but not before the weekend.

Comment: Thanks dear for the time you put into this.

Answer (score 4):

This nonlinear system of equations is difficult to solve numerically, because the coefficient of the leading derivative, `psi''''[r]`, is `1 - 3 xx1 psi''[r]^2`.  Thus, the equations are singular for sufficiently large `xx1`, unless `psi''[r]]^2` becomes correspondingly small.  Unfortunately, it does not, at least for the specified boundary conditions.

The equations in the question, slightly reformatted, are

```
eqn1 = D[psi[r], {r, 4}] - xx1*D[D[psi[r], {r, 2}]^3, {r, 2}] + 
    D[p[r], {r, 1}] - D[psi[r], {r, 2}] == 0;
eqn2 = D[p[r], {r, 2}] + D[psi[r], {r, 2}]*(1 - xx1*D[psi[r], {r, 2}]^2) == 0;
eqns = {eqn1, eqn2, psi[3/2] == 3/4, psi[-1] == -3/4, psi'[3/2] == -1, psi'[-1] == -1, 
    p[3/2] == 0, p[-1] == 1};
sol = NDSolve[eqns, {psi, p}, {r, -1, 3/2}];
```

With `xx1 = .0045`, these equations produce the solution,

```
Plot[Evaluate[{psi[r], p[r]} /. sol], {r, -1, 3/2}, AxesLabel -> {r, "Psi, P"}]
Plot[Evaluate[{psi''[r], p'[r]} /. sol], {r, -.99999, 3/2}, 
    AxesLabel -> {r, "Psi'', P'"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]
[image]

However, for `x = 0.0046`, `NDSolve` fails with the error

```
NDSolve::ndsz: At r == 1.4840214740085271`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>
```

Evidently, `NDSolve`, which automatically uses the shooting method for boundary value problems, had chosen an initial guess which caused an integration to encounter the singularity described above.  However, we can help `NDSolve` by giving it a better initial guess by means of the option

```
Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {p'[-1] == 1.003441714435437`, 
    psi''[-1] == 5.874921755046804`, psi'''[-1] == -50.65287823788822`, 
    p[-1] == 1, psi[-1] == -3/4, psi'[-1] == -1}}
```

which yields for `xx1 = 0.00867` the plots

[image]
[image]

`psi''[-1]` is noticeably larger here than in the `xx1 = 0.0045` case, and the coefficient of psi''''[-1] is about `0.0098`.  From watching the behavior of the solutions as `xx1` is increased, I would guess that the upper bound on `xx1` is less than `0.01`.  I obtained the `"StartingInitialConditions"` by using for them the values of

```
{p'[r], psi''[r], psi'''[r]} /. sol /. r -> -1
```

determined from the previous value of `xx1` to carry out the calculation for a slightly larger value of `xxi`.  I did this by hand, although automating the process would not be difficult.  Using `ParametricNDSolve` with `FindRoot` instead of `NDSolve` with `Shooting` probably also would be helpful, because the former is more flexible.

Comment: Following up on @bbgodfrey's suggestion, I modified the code I used to automate a similar problem (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109538/trying-to-find-a-temperature-profile-with-a-nonlinear-2nd-order-ode-ndsolve-ver/109595).  I got as far as `xx1=0.008758`, where `{p'[r], psi''[r], psi'''[r]}={0.999947,6.07272,-168.283}`.  I can post that code if you like.

Comment: @ChrisK I will love to see your try.

Answer (score 3):

This is a follow-up to @bbgodfrey's suggestion to automate stepping through increasing `xx1` values, using previous results to inform initial guesses for `{p'[-1], psi''[-1], psi'''[-1]}` in the `Shooting` method.  As noted by @bbgodfrey, there seems to be a singularity just beyond `xx1=0.008758`.

```
(* initial guess *)
{Dp0, D2psi0, D3psi0} = {Dp, D2psi, D3psi} =
{1.0054755681712373`, 5.809999047134965`, -40.556086842902005`};

dxx1 = 0.000001; (* step size *)

Do[
  eqn1 = D[psi[r], {r, 4}] - xx1*D[D[psi[r], {r, 2}]^3, {r, 2}] + 
    D[p[r], {r, 1}] - D[psi[r], {r, 2}] == 0;
  eqn2 = D[p[r], {r, 2}] + 
    D[psi[r], {r, 2}]*(1 - xx1*D[psi[r], {r, 2}]^2) == 0;
  eqns = {eqn1, eqn2, psi[3/2] == 3/4, psi[-1] == -3/4, 
   psi'[3/2] == -1, psi'[-1] == -1, p[3/2] == 0, p[-1] == 1};

  sol = NDSolve[eqns, {psi, p}, {r, -1, 3/2}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", 
      "StartingInitialConditions" -> {p'[-1] == Dp0, 
        psi''[-1] == D2psi0, psi'''[-1] == D3psi0, p[-1] == 1, 
        psi[-1] == -3/4, psi'[-1] == -1}}][[1]];

   Print[xx1, " guess:", {Dp0, D2psi0, D3psi0}, 
    " actual:", {p'[-1], psi''[-1], psi'''[-1]} /. sol];

   (* move old results *)
   {Dpold, D2psiold, D3psiold} = {Dp, D2psi, D3psi};
   (* add new results *)
   {Dp, D2psi, D3psi} = {p'[-1], psi''[-1], psi'''[-1]} /. sol;
   (* linear extrapolation for next guess *)
   {Dp0, D2psi0, D3psi0} = {2 Dp - Dpold, 2 D2psi - D2psiold, 2 D3psi - D3psiold};

, {xx1, 0.0086, 0.008758, dxx1}];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain a *linear* relation between Psi[r] and P[r] as follows:

```
Simplify[First[Eqn1] - First[D[Eqn2, {r, 2}]]] == 0
```

This relation is clearly integrable, does not depend upon XX1, and you can use it to eliminate Psi[r]. This may assist in your goal of solving the nonlinear system, by reducing it to a single equation in Psi.