# Passing starting values to FindRoot when called by the Shooting Method of NDSolve

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

According to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html#659822336) of the `NDSolve` `Method -> "Shooting"` option, it is possible to pass to `FindRoot` (which is called by this option) a single starting value per boundary condition, and the `FindRoot` `Method` and `MaxIterations` option values.  However, according to the Details and Options section of its [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html), `FindRoot`, called directly, also accepts *pairs* of starting values:

> `FindRoot[lhs == rhs, {x, Subscript[x, 0], Subscript[x, 1]}]` searches for a solution using `Subscript[x, 0]` and `Subscript[x, 1]` as the first two values of `x`, avoiding the use of derivatives.

or starting values *with search bounds*:

> `FindRoot[lhs == rhs, {x, Subscript[x, start], Subscript[x, min], Subscript[x, max]}]` searches for a solution, stopping the search if `x` ever gets outside the range `Subscript[x, min]` to `Subscript[x, max]`.

Is there a way to pass either of these alternative starting value specifications through the `NDSolve` `Method -> "Shooting"` option to `FindRoot`?

I recognize that it is possible to achieve this functionality by replacing `NDSolve` with `Method -> "Shooting"` by `ParametricNDSolve` in combination with `FindRoot` but would prefer to use some "secret" `Shooting` suboption, if it exists.

Comment: No, this is not possible with the present implementation. Only single starting values are accepted and passed through to `FindRoot`.

Comment: @ilian, I fear that you are right.  The second capability, starting-values with search bounds, would be especially useful, because it would provide a way to bound the "Shooting" process away from singularities.  See, for instance, my answer to [110692](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110692/1063).  What would be the best way to prevail upon Wolfram, Inc to add this capability in the next release?  Thanks.

Comment: @bb, you could try e-mailing your suggestion/proposal to them, and hopefully it gets taken up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make my comment into an answer,

> No, this is not possible with the present implementation. Only single
>   starting values are accepted and passed through to [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html).

Thank you for sending this suggestion for a possible improvement of the functionality, it will be reviewed by the appropriate developers.

Comment: Thanks for encouraging the `NDSolve` developers to considering this improvement.  the "Shooting" `Method` is important, and there are many ways that it could be improved.