# Solving stiff boundary value problem

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, boundary-condition-at-infinity

Im trying to solve a nonlinear ODE with boundary conditions, the simplified problem reads for example
$$ k \frac{\mathrm d^2 T}{\mathrm d x^2} = T^4\, , \quad x \in[0,\, 1]\, , \\
T(0)=0.9\,,\quad T(1)=1\, ,$$
where $k \in [0,\infty)$ and $T >0$. Im especially interested in solutions, where $k$ becomes small.

For values of $k \geq 1$ NDSolve finds solutions without any problems:

```
k = 1;
TSol[x_] = T[x] /.NDSolve[
    {k*D[T[x], {x, 2}] == T[x]^4, T[0] == 0.9, T[1] == 1}, T, {x, 0, 1}];
Plot[TSol[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

However as $k$ approaches $0.1$, NDSolve fails to find a solution. The code

```
k = 0.1;
TSol[x_] = T[x] /.NDSolve[
    {k*D[T[x], {x, 2}] == T[x]^4, T[0] == 0.9, T[1] == 1}, T, {x, 0, 1}];
Plot[TSol[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

returns

```
NDSolve::ndsz: At x == 0.5188259855491343`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.
```

I have tried to solve it using a shooting Method as well as the StiffnessSwitching Method, which both fail.

Any help is appreciated, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution based on Numerical Shooting**

The `NDSolve` `{Method -> "Shooting", ...}` option sometimes does not work well for problems like this.  The following approach, patterned after my answer to [147207](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147585/1063), is an effective alternative.  Define,

```
TSol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{k*D[T[x], {x, 2}] == T[x]^4, T[0] == 9/10, T'[0] == tp, 
    WhenEvent[T[x] > 1 || T[x] < 0, "StopIntegration"]}, T, {x, 0, 1}, {k, tp}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

Then, plot the distance that `ParametricNDSolveValue` can integrate the ODE, given values of `k` and `T'[0]`.  Here, we choose `k == 1/100`.

```
plt = Plot[Quiet@(TSol[1/100, tp]["Domain"])[[1, 2]], {tp, -6, -4}, 
    PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"T'[0]", Subscript[x, max]},
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 14], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

The value of `T'[0]` solving the problem must lie in the flat portion of the plot.  Find the endpoints of that flat region.

```
lim = Flatten[{First@First[#], First@Last[#]} & /@ 
    DeleteCases[SplitBy[Cases[plt, Line[a__] :> a, Infinity] // Last, Last], 
    a_ /; Length[a] == 1]]
(* {-4.88537, -4.82786} *)
```

Now, define a function that improves the accuracy of the upper point of that range.

```
hh[k_, bl0_, bu0_] := Module[{bl = bl0, bu = bu0, zt, bt}, 
    Do[bt = (bl + bu)/2; zt = Quiet@(TSol[k, bt]); 
    If[zt["Domain"][[1, 2]] < 1, bu = bt, bl = bt], {i, 60}]; bl]
```

and apply it to the upper point determined from the plot.

```
hh[1/100, Last@lim - 10^-3, Last@lim + 10^-3]
(* -4.82723664533214` *)
```

With this value of `T[0]`, the desired curve is obtained.

```
Plot[TSol[1/100, %][x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, All}, AxesLabel -> {r, T}, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 14], ImageSize -> Large]
TSol[1/100, %%][1]
```

[image]

```
(* 0.99999999999999159459228610094 *)
```

with a precision of about 15.

**Largely Symbolic Solution from DSolve**

The ODE in this question is identical to that in [151385](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151385/1063), but the boundary conditions add additional complexity.  Begin from the implicit soluton for `T[r]` from the earlier question,

```
eq = (Hypergeometric2F1[1/5, 1/2, 6/5, -((2 T[x]^5)/(5 k C[1]))]^2 T[x]^2)/C[1] == 
    (x + C[2])^2;
```

and repeat the evaluation of `C[2]`, here based on the `T[0] == 0.9`

```
Reverse[Simplify[Sqrt[#], x + C[2] < 0 && 
    Hypergeometric2F1[1/5, 1/2, 6/5, -((2 T[x]^5)/(5 k C[1]))] T[x] > 0] & /@ eq];
Rule @@ (% /. x -> 0 /. T[0] -> 9/10);
eq0 = (%% /. %) /. C[1] -> -2 c/(5 k);
FullSimplify[D[eq0, x]] /. x -> r0;
eq00 = Subtract @@ eq0 /. c -> T[x0]^5

(* -r + (9 Hypergeometric2F1[1/5, 1/2, 6/5, 59049/(100000 T[x0]^5)] Sqrt[-(k/T[x0]^5)])/(2 Sqrt[10]) - 
   Sqrt[5/2] Hypergeometric2F1[1/5, 1/2, 6/5, T[r]^5/T[r0]^5] T[r] Sqrt[-(k/T[r0]^5)] *)
```

Note, however, the `T'[x]` vanishes, not at `x == 1` as in the earlier question, but at some smaller value of `x`, here called `x0`.  Further, employing the `T[1] == 1` boundary condition requires choosing a different root of `eq`.

```
Reverse[Simplify[Sqrt[#] - x, x + C[2] > 0 && 
    Hypergeometric2F1[1/5, 1/2, 6/5, -((2 T[x]^5)/(5 k C[1]))] T[x] > 0] & /@ eq];
Rule @@ (% /. x -> 1 /. T[1] -> 1);
eq1 = (%% /. %) /. C[1] -> -2 c/(5 k);
FullSimplify[D[eq1, x]] /. x -> x0
eq11 = -Subtract @@ eq1 /. c -> T[x0]^5

(* 1 - x - Sqrt[5/2] Hypergeometric2F1[1/5, 1/2, 6/5, 1/T[x0]^5] Sqrt[-(k/T[x0]^5)] + 
    Sqrt[5/2] Hypergeometric2F1[1/5, 1/2, 6/5, T[r]^5/T[x0]^5] T[x] Sqrt[-(k/T[x0]^5)] *)
```

Now, eliminate `x0` and obtain `T[x0]` from `eq00 == 0` and `eq11 == 0`.

```
FullSimplify[(eq00 - eq11) /. x -> x0];
FindRoot[(% == 0) /. k -> 1/100, {T[x0], 1}] // Chop
(* {T[x0] -> 0.380107} *)
```

`T[x0]` visibly is  the minimum value of `T[x]`, as expected.  Finally, plot the corresponding curve.

```
temin = T[r0] /. %;
arg = {{eq00, tem}, {eq11, tem}} /. %% /. k -> 1/100 /. T[x] -> tem /. x -> 0;
ParametricPlot[arg // Chop, {tem, temin, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, All}, AxesLabel -> {r, T}, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 14], ImageSize -> Large]
```

which yields a plot identical to the one concluding the solution above.

Answer (score 11):

### Relaxation solution

Your ODE is 
$$
k \frac{d^2 T}{dx^2} - T^4 = 0,  \qquad T(0) = 0.9, \qquad T(1) = 1
$$
where $T$ is a function of $x$.  We attempt instead to solve the related PDE
$$
k \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} - T^4 = \frac{\partial T}{\partial t} \qquad T(0,t) = 0.9, \qquad T(1,t) = 1 \qquad T(x,0) = f(x)
$$
If the solution of $T(x,t)$ approaches a constant with respect to $t$ as $t \to \infty$, then the resulting function $T(x,\infty)$ will be a solution to the original ODE.  The choice of the function $f(x)$ will *hopefully* not make a major difference to the resulting solution (but see below).  To make things easier for the solution, we can pick a function that agrees with the boundary conditions, i.e, $f(0) = 0.9$ and $f(1) = 1$;  but this is neither necessary nor sufficient to get a solution to the ODE.

If we pick $f(x) = 0.9 + 0.1 x$, Mathematica has no trouble finding a numerical solution of this PDE:

```
k = 0.01;
f[x_] = 0.9 + 0.1 x;
tf = 1000;
eqns = {D[T[x, t], t] == k D[T[x, t], {x, 2}] - T[x, t]^4, T[x, 0] == f[x], T[0, t] == 0.9, T[1, t] == 1}
soln = NDSolve[eqns, T[x, t], {t, 0, tf}, {x, 0, 1}]
Plot[(T[x, t] /. soln) /. t -> tf, {x,0,1}]
```

[image]

When using this approach, the final time must be chosen to be sufficiently large that the solution "settles down" to the steady-state solution (with $\partial T /\partial t = 0$).  Here we have picked $t_f = 1000$, but this turns out to be overkill;  in fact, the solution has settled down most of the way to its final value by $t = 30$ or so.  Here are the values of $T(x,t)$ for $t = 0, 1, 3, 10$, and $30$:
[image]

#### Caveats

One does have to be careful using this technique;  just because Mathematica does not find a solution using this technique does not necessarily mean that a solution does not exist.  For example, if we pick

```
f[x_] = 0.9 + 0.1 x - 6 x (1 - x)
```

as our initial guess, we get the same solution.  However, if we pick

```
f[x_] = 0.9 + 0.1 x - 7 x (1 - x)
```

the solution to the PDE does not "settle down" as $t \to \infty$.  It's therefore best practice when using this technique to make a good "initial guess" for the final solution;  the closer your guess is to the final solution, the quicker it will converge to the final solution.

There are also many non-linear ODEs for which this technique fails utterly, but for which shooting methods like [bbgodfrey's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151619/27813) succeed (and vice versa.)  This just happens to be one for which both methods work.  I can't do much better than quote *Numerical Recipes* here:

> Until you have enough experience to make your own judgment between the two methods, you might wish to follow the advice of your authors, who are notorious computer gunslingers:  We always shoot first, and only then relax.

Comment: Very effective demonstration of relaxation (+1).